# Facebook Auth log out with Rails and Parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble finding a way to log out from facebook. We are logging in using `window.location = '/auth/facebook'` which redirects the user to a facebook login page, and calls a callback route `/auth/facebook/callback`(declared in `developers.facebook.com`) to a method in my `session_controller/create`.

The `session_controller/create` method looks like this

```
  def create
#get auth hash from omniauth
auth = auth_hash
@data = {}
@session_data = {}
@data['id'] = auth['uid']
@data['access_token'] = auth['credentials']['token']
#time must be in iso format, see parse rest api for details under linking
@expiry = Time.at(auth['credentials']['expires_at']).iso8601
@data['expiration_date'] = @expiry
#create new linking user object
user = Parse::User::Facebook.new(@data)
# add other user information to body of PARSE::USER::FACEBOOK instance
user.body['email'] = auth['info']['email']
user.body['auth'] = true
user.body['fullname'] = auth['info']['name']
user.body['ip'] = request.remote_ip
user.body['image'] = auth['info']['image'] if auth['info']['image']
user.body['admin'] = false
user.body['facebookId'] = auth['uid']
user.body['facebookToken'] = auth['credentials']['token']
user.body['has_seen_web_tutorial'] = false
@current_user = user.save
#save necessary session information
session['name'] = @current_user['fullname']
session['points'] = @current_user['points']
session['objectId'] = @current_user['objectId']
session['sessionToken'] = @current_user['sessionToken']
session['image'] = @current_user['image']
session['location'] = @current_user['location']

@session_data['name'] = session['name']
@session_data['fullname'] = @current_user['fullname']
@session_data['points'] = session['points']
@session_data['objectId'] = session['objectId']
@session_data['image'] = session['image']
if auth['info']['image']
    File.open('temp_face.png', 'wb') do |file|
      file << open(auth['info']['image'], :allow_redirections => :safe).read
    end
    photo = Parse::File.new({
      :body => IO.read("temp_face.png"),
      :local_filename => "temp_face.png",
      :content_type => "image/png"
    })
    photo.save
    #user.body['image'] = photo
end
image = Parse::Object.new("ImageUploads")
image['fileKey'] = photo
image['owner'] = Parse::Pointer.new({"className" => "_User", "objectId" => session['objectId']})
image['type'] = 'profile'
#image['location']
saved_image = image.save
redirect_to listing_index_path
 end
```

I am having trouble trying to log out. Very new to rails. Any help please?
Thank you

Comment: Just fyi parse service is being discontinued

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII yes I am aware. We will migrate in a month or two. For now need to ship the product.